# dynamic jQuery variable name

Tags: jquery

I am working on generating gantt chart using jquery. Have searched alot, but didn't reach any conclusion on if it is possible to declare a dynamic jquery variable. Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

First, I am trying to generate a dynamic main task from the database. I want to make the variable name dynamic so that i can dynamically assign it subtasks. want to do somthing like:

```
forloop{
var task+taskID = MainGanttTask(taskID...)
}

forloop{
task+taskID.addChild(childTaskID...)
}
```

So, is there any way to get my "task+taskID" variable working?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use arrays?

```
forloop{
    tasks[taskID] = MainGanttTask(taskID...)
}

forloop{
    tasks[taskID].addChild(childTaskID...)
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, but the jquery plugin that i am using, doesn't accept array, needs the input for the task name to be a variable.

Comment: What is that plugin? If we know maybe we can help you more.

Comment: not really a plugin. a class which i customized, got it from http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/index.shtml

Comment: solved. just needed to declare the array before using it. thanx

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was helpful. You can learn from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about accepting answers. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info! Thanks